# PostSharp Express. Handle multiple exceptions

Tags: c#, postsharp

I have a method like this:

```
public static void DoWork()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something...");
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException exAN)
    {
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException exDBZ)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

I want to use PostSharp Express to write an aspect to handle the exceptions.

If the exception is the only one, it is simple; I inherit from `OnExceptionAspect` and handle the exception in the `OnException` method.

But what if I want to handle multiple exceptions?

Using the same aspect twice decorating the method generates a nested try/catch in IL and is not what I want.

Can someone provide me an example of how to write an aspect for a situation such this?

Comment: Does it mean that you need an aspect that handles just selected exception types. E.g. if you decorate a method by `[MyExceptionHandler(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]` then the aspect should handle just ArgumentNullExceptions thrown from the method, but DivideByZeroException should stay unhandled. Is it right?

Comment: Hi Jakub, no. The syntax in the C# example means that i can handle ArgumentNullException or DivideByZeroException or any type of exception in the specified order. I look first for ArgumentNullException, if the exception not is a ArgumentNullException, look for DivideByZeroException, otherwise catch a generic exception. I can handle something using many aspect of type [MyExceptionHandler(typeof(ArgumentNullException))], but the generated code is with too many nested try/catch.

Comment: Would it be possible to check the Type of MethodExecutionArgs.Exception and inject the types by constructor? public MyException(params Type[] exceptionTypes) { this.exceptionTypes = exceptionTypes; } public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args) { if (exceptionTypes.Contains(args.Exception.GetType())) { args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue; } }